# Why is my dynamically added event handler not firing consistently

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello i basically added datagridviews dynamically to my windows form application, and added cellClick event handlers dynamically by looping through all the datagridview control, however my event doesnt fire consistently, like when i click really fast it wont clear the selection sometimes. here is my code

```
 void DGV_CellClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
       dgv.ClearSelection();
    }

 foreach(KeyValuePair<int,datagridview>entry in DGVCollection)
    {
       datagridview dgv = entry.value;
       dgv.CellClick+= DGV_CellClick;
    }
```

Comment: It's possible that the CellDoubleClick event get's fired instead of the CellClick event.

Comment: @Innominatum That's a nice catch! You'd better post it as an answer

Comment: @Innominatum oh but how does that even happen? i did not add any event handler for the CellDoubleClick Event, if thats the case it must explain why it works consistently when i click slowly

Comment: Try attaching a Eventhandler to the DoubleClickEvent and set a breakpoint at the DoubleClickEvent handler.

Comment: @Innominatum ah ok thanks ill try that, and yes it is the double click event causing this, whenever i try double clicking the cells the cellClick isnt fired and the selection in the datagridview doesnt clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "however my event doesnt fire consistently, like when i click really fast it wont clear the selection sometimes. here is my code"

It's possible that the CellDoubleClick event get's fired instead of the CellClick event.

You could take a look at this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Hm is there anyway to prevent this?

Comment: With the knowledge that I have I think that blocking cannot be done. You could bind the same eventhandler to the doubleclick event.

Comment: @Jimi sorry what do you mean by signature?

Comment: The event delegates have the same signature `(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)`. You can use the same handler for both. You'll notice that, when you double-click a cell, the event is raised twice. You could use a StopWatch to measure it and discard the event (just `return`) if it's around [SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.doubleclicktime).